# Datarow setters performance dependent on datatable column count?

Tags: .net, performance, dataset, datarow

We've recently experienced dramatically slower performance for datatables with large column counts (~100-200).  After some debugging, I think the lag comes from datarow's set item methods going much slower as column count increases.  Here is our benchmark, setting the same row item in a loop:

```
 Dim sw As New Stopwatch
        Dim cnt = 10 ^ 6 - 1

        Debug.Print("-- Row setter test for 10 column datatable --")

        Dim dt As New DataTable
        For i = 0 To 9
            dt.Columns.Add("Column" & i.ToString)
        Next
        Dim row As DataRow = dt.Rows.Add

        Dim col = dt.Columns(9)
        sw.Restart()
        For i = 0 To cnt
            row.Item(col) = 3.14
        Next
        sw.Stop()
        Debug.Print("RowSet time:  " & sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds.ToString)


        Debug.Print("-- Row setter test for 100 column datatable --")

        dt = New DataTable
        For i = 0 To 99
            dt.Columns.Add("Column" & i.ToString)
        Next
        row = dt.Rows.Add

        col = dt.Columns(9)
        sw.Restart()
        For i = 0 To cnt
            row.Item(col) = 3.14
        Next
        sw.Stop()
        Debug.Print("RowSet time:  " & sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds.ToString)
```

...which outputs 0.95 sec for 10 column table, 5.8 sec for 100 column table - a significant difference.  Results are similar using the other overloaded set methods, by 
column name and column index.

I don't understand these results.  Shouldn't the datarow item get/set be an O(1) operation with respect to total column count?  Surely the datatable has indexed its column collection in some fashion?

Comment: Are you purposefully not using the column index to do the setting?

Comment: As stated I tried setting by all 3 methods - column, column index, column string.  By column is slightly faster than column index on my machine, the results of the benchmark are the same regardless.

Comment: Very surprising. I would have thought column index would have been much faster.  I also just realized you're only accessing a single column across multiple rows, so that voids my original question anyway.

Comment: I also would have guessed column index to be faster, but then again I also would have guessed row item setter speed to be independent of column count, so I'm pretty confused as to what's going on.